# Remote access to xubuntu stops when its screen is locked

Tags: xubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc

I access a desktop (xubuntu 20.04) remotely from another desktop (ubuntu 21.04) using VNC protocol of Remmina.

I have installed vino in xubuntu to enable it for remote access.

Remote access to xubuntu works fine when that computer is unlocked, and stops working when it is locked.

Could you please tell me a way out ?

Thanks