# Better Linux Operatings System for fast remote access

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

I want to access a computer remotely from my Ubuntu [20.04] Computer.

I installed Ubuntu [20.04] in that Computer, but remote access  doesn't work smoothly [mouse pointer drags not so smoothly].

Next Installed Xubuntu [20.04], which works well in remote access, but there are some problems it it. For Ex. [Remote access to xubuntu stops when its screen is locked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379639/remote-access-to-xubuntu-stops-when-its-screen-is-locked)

How's Lubuntu ? Is it better than Xubuntu for access remotely ?

Could you please tell us which Linux OS I should install in it for better performance.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remote access to xubuntu stops when its screen is locked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379639/remote-access-to-xubuntu-stops-when-its-screen-is-locked) From a security standpoint this is one of the worst things you can do, because when the screen is unlocked on a remote unattended computer anyone who walks up to that computer has access to its operating system.

Comment: I'd recommend not using a GUI.  Text requires a tiny fraction of the bandwidth compared to a GUI.  Your question is also asking for off-topic *opinions* as to what is fastest (see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) and would be better asked on a forum (which is https://ubuntuforums.org/ for Ubuntu) in my opinion.